# node.js express-session not working in router

Tags: node.js, express, session, router

i have a some problem

i'm using express-session middleware in my app

it work

but

It did not work on any particular router.

my code is follows

//app.js

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'D$YTRH#%#$@^$#YR',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}))

//assign session in outside

app.get(/*, (req, res, next)=>{
    req.session.outSide = "outSideBlah"
    next()
}

//my session Check middleware
app.get('/*', (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log(req.session._inSide)
    console.log(req.session._outSide)
    next()
}

const auth = require('./routes/auth.js')(express)
app.use('/auth', auth)
```

//auth.js (my router)

```
//assign session in router ( inside)
module.exports = (express) => {
    const auth = express.Router()
    auth.post('/login', (req, res)=>{
        req.session._inside = 'insideBlah'  //Assign a session here
    ............some auth code ......
    }
    return auth
}
```

after login

in my session Check middleware

```
console.log(req.session.inSide) // undefined
console.log(req.session.outSide) // "outSideBlah"
```

Even though I assigned req.session.inSide in auth.js

req.session.inside is undefined

What is the problem?

Why can not I access a session assigned by my router (auth.js)?

somebody help me.. thank you...

Comment: You assigned session in `_inside`, you should do `console.log(_inside)`

Answer (score 0):

Also I think you should use `*` instead of `/*`.